# Iptable : Redirect https to http except for specific host

Tags: iptables, redirect, https

I have multiple websites on my server, and just one of them is through https (say : https://admin.example.com).

But if an user tries to access to https://www.example.com, he got a warning about an invalid SSL certificate, dedicated to admin.example.com and wrong for www.example.com (obviously!).

I'd like to redirect every https request that is not for admin.example.com to the original host, but in http, is this possible?

To be clear :

- https://admin.example.com : no redirect
- http://admin.example.com : redirect to https://admin.example.com (done via NGinx configuration)
- https://whatever.example.com : redirect to http://whatever.example.com
- https://whatever.example.com/query/string?complex=1 : redirect to http://whatever.example.com/query/string?complex=1

Is this possible via iptables? if so, how?

Thank you for your help, I appreciate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatives to solve the warning problem would be one of the following

- Close the *https* port all together (port 443)
- Buy a SSL-certificate that is valid for **all domains**
- Put the *https*-site on a seperate IP-address, and only open port 443 on that IP.

If you absolutely want to use a redirect, you would have to send the redirect to the browser **after** the SSL-certificate have been presented to the browser, and then also after the warning have shown. There is probably some way you could redirect port 443 to port 80 with iptables, but I do not know of any method that would do that in a "good" method, as a browser requesting a site over *https* assumes it meets a SSL-enabled site.

Comment: if the secured site will be on separate IP, why would he need cert for all domains?

Comment: If you read the first sentence, it says "(...) one of the following" He would not need a certificate for all domains if he put the secured site on a seperate IP. I'm sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Ops, didn't see that. But then, how is the first option (close 443) is solution at all, he'll not have ssl for admin site?

Comment: still, you have +1

Comment: Closing port 443 would stop the SSL-warning from being shown, which is what I have given alternatives to in the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could not redirect *https* traffic to *http*. This redirect must be seen by the browser, to know, that there will be non-SSL Traffic.

You should either buy a valid SSL Certificate with is widely trusted, or close the *https* port.

You could redirect via some configuration parameters for *Apache*, but you will still get the warning first.